# How can I get a Mandarin teacher while living in a small town without Chinese schools/institutions?

Tags: pronunciation, learning

I've been learning Chinese for 2 months and I'm finding it too hard to learn by myself. So as I asked in the title, I'd like to get a tutor so that I can learn basic grammar and practice conversations. I hope someone can give advice! Thank you in advance.

Comment: 有钱能使鬼推磨 .......

Comment: R u native English speaker, if so, you can do language exchange program?

Comment: Language exchange is a good idea, bro.

But where exactly do you live, China or other countries?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- Finding an **online [tandem partner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_language_learning)** who speaks Chinese and is interested in learning a language that you can teach (your native language or another language in which you have a near-native proficiency). [Mosalingua](http://www.mosalingua.com/en/how-to-find-conversation-partners-best-language-exchange-sites/) lists a few sites where you can find a tandem partner; there are several other ones, e.g. [Polyglot club](http://polyglotclub.com/). See also [How I found Chinese speaking friends online](http://www.chinese-forums.com/index.php?/topic/32477-how-i-found-chinese-speaking-friends-online/) on ChineseForums.com.
- Finding a **paid tutor or teacher**. The [classifieds section](http://www.chinese-forums.com/index.php?/forum/29-classifieds/) on ChineseForums.com might be helpful here. Some of the sites that help you connect with tandem partners can also help you find paid tutors or teachers. The actual teaching may work through Skype lessons or through video conferencing functionality built into the site.

Comment: Good！I always hope that duolingo has a Chinese teaching section so I can learn a language like playing a game.None of other apps can help me like a real teacher, so I still decided to find a tutor online.Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I know a online website offer some Chinese courses: [Chinlingo](http://www.chinlingo.com). I don't know what kind of method they use, but I believe they have some free courses and one-to-one courses.

And if you need tandem-partner and you are a English native speaker, maybe we can help each other, I am learning English and perparing TOEFL :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that really helped me was Middlebury online. It costs a bit, but if you are working through a school or university, they'll typically cover the cost. If not, it doesn't cost too much. That really helped me because you can speak with a tutor online and set up lessons.